# Utilising Stripe for ordering products with their Order API and variable shipping

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I have been trying to implement Stripe and without having to worry about the shipping costs it's very very simple, I had this code that worked fine:

```
<form action="payment.php" method="POST">
    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
            data-key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            data-amount="2500"
            data-name="some name"
            data-description="some description"
            data-label="{{ order.button_name|e }}"
            data-locale="auto"
            data-zip-code="true"
            data-billing-address="true"
            data-shipping-address="true"
            data-currency="aud">
    </script>
</form>
```

Now, as I understand it I have to work out / or retrieve the shipping cost from Stripe *before* I populate this code (or dynamically update it) so I can factor in shipping.

I have been reading about the [Orders API](https://stripe.com/docs/orders) and it seem you need to create an **order item** to: *retrieve tax and shipping costs from Stripe*

So with this in mind it sounds like it needs to be done before the user clicks the button to pay so you have the correct shipping costs to add to the amount to charge them - but I am confused, shouldn't an "order" only be created only *after* they actually *ordered* an item; but it seems like that is just a terminology issue from how the docs read.

Secondly, to be able to calculate the shipping cost I would need to grab the users shipping address off of them prior to letting them launch the payment modal, so that means I won't be asking for it in the payment modal - however in that case, how does Stripe know their address information if they are not entering it in the payment modal?

It sounds like I would pass the *order id* returned from the **Order API** to Stripe through the checkout somehow?

So basically I'm just confused at how this changes things when using the Order API in conjunction with Checkout.

What is the process after getting the *Order Object* returned and how does it differ to the current code I am working with above and does the server side code differ from the standard Checkout? It seems the standard checking is "creating a charge", eg:

```
// Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

// Token is created using Checkout or Elements!
// Get the payment token ID submitted by the form:
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
    'amount' => 999,
    'currency' => 'usd',
    'description' => 'Example charge',
    'source' => $token,
]);
```

...and using the Order API we're doing something different:

```
// Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

// Token is created using Checkout or Elements!
// Get the payment token ID submitted by the form:
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

$order = \Stripe\Order::retrieve('or_1D2jGkKFk4dvoSd9xVrShgsg');
$order->pay(['source' => $token]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's not a complete integration between Checkout and Orders. What you will want to do here is create an order when you display your site's "checkout" page. You'd add the items the user is going to purchase to the order, as well as the user's shipping address to get accurate shipping and tax information to display. There's no way to get the shipping information **from** Stripe Checkout and pass that back into the Order object, so you need to collect it ahead of time. Then, when your user chooses a shipping method, you'd use that to set up Stripe Checkout to display the total correctly.

It may be simpler to implement shipping and tax logic separately and simply create a charge for the total amount, which is what software such as WooCommerce do when integrated with Stripe (rather than use Orders).

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I will look into doing it separately as per your suggestion, but was wondering when you say "Then, when your user chooses a shipping method, you'd use that to set up Stripe Checkout to display the total correctly." - so I guess you would have to load the button/form via AJAX since updating the `data-*` fields dynamically isn't going to cut it?

Comment: You'd want to make your own button and use the "custom" integration path documented here: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom

This allows you to set the amount dynamically from Javascript. With Orders yes, you'd send an AJAX request to your backend to update the Order, and then send the shipping + tax amounts back to the browser so you can update the page and Checkout object.

Comment: Thanks - yeah, that's the way I ended up doing it - with the custom integration.